# PHP parse error

Tags: php, mysql

Im using XAMPP, and what i've done is tryng to connect to the database on phpmyadmin, however an error is prompt saying syntax error, the code is right however.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\csgopit\connect.php on line 10

The code itself is really simple and i dont understand why it's not working.

```
<?php
//connect.php
$server = 'localhost';
$username   = 'zimmer';
$password   = 'vegas2';
$database   = 'csgopit';


if(!mysql_connect($server, $username,  $password)){    exit('Error: could not establish database connection');}
if(!mysql_select_db($database){    exit('Error: could not select the database');}
?>
```

The database on PHPMYADMIN has that user and password in it.

I've started learning MYSQL a while ago, and i'm interested in php aswell, so starting with it right now actually, pardon if the question is dumb.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if(!mysql_select_db($database){    exit('Error: could not select the database');}
                             ^ missing closing if ) parenthesis here
```

Comment: Thank you, rookie mistake!
Good clear explanation, thank you.